# Is there an online source for European Instrument Approach Procedures?

Tags: iaps, aeronautical-charts, easa, eu

The FAA offers instrument approach procedures on their website free of charge ([FAA Charts](http://aeronav.faa.gov/index.asp?xml=aeronav/applications/d_tpp)).  Is there a similar site provided by EASA or the EU?

Comment: The other question, http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1539/are-the-airport-taxi-plans-available-online, also has some pointers (the question is about airport charts, but the sites have approach and departure charts too).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Eurocontrol has an online repository of [European Aeronatical Information Services](http://www.ead.eurocontrol.int/eadcms/eadsite/index.php.html).

You'll need to register, but the basic service is free.

By default, the application is JAVA applet based, which works not in the best way. After logging on, you can change the default behaviour to HTML based, which makes it more user friendly.

[image]

Then clicking "Enter Application" will bring to the next level.

Here you'll find several reporting options, but what you are interested in is located under "PAMS Light [AIP]"

[image]

Select the country you are interested in, "Charts" for AIP type and "AD" for Aerodrome and there you have the charts.

Comment: It is still a Java applet involved even if you change it to plain HTML, don't know where or how, but you can't use it without Java. Don't ask me why, I've battled with it for quite some time.

Comment: @roe, strange. It works here without problems with my JAVA plugin disabled (both Firefox & Chrome). Are you sure you have selected "Simple mode" and applied the change?

Comment: @DeltaLima I am very sure. I'm not able to log on, or rather, as soon as I successfully authenticate it throws me out saying my Java is too old (< 1.6.something). I don't even have a Java plugin installed. Have to run it through my windows VM.

Comment: @roe I have the same now after logging out, restarting my browser and logging in again it doesn't let me past the authentication and complains about my Java plugin. I am **not** going to install an outdated security flawed Java version for them...

Answer (score 1):

Each European country has it's own set of charts (AIP) and they're all different. Jeppesen company is making big buck by collecting data from national AIP's and then converting it into single unified output format. Lido company is also making the same thing, but they have less airports in their database and it's only for C, D class aircraft (i.e. for airlines).

Comment: As DeltaLime explained in his answer above, Eurocontrol published AIS information for all member countries in the EAD.