# Is there an online source for Canadian Instrument Approach Procedures?

Tags: iaps, aeronautical-charts, transport-canada

The [FAA](http://aeronav.faa.gov/index.asp?xml=aeronav/applications/d_tpp) offers instrument approach procedures on their website free of charge, and [EASA](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1276/is-there-an-online-source-for-european-instrument-approach-procedures) does too.  Does Canada have them online for us to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not officially, no. The official approaches are available in a PDF format to download for 20 CAD for each volume.

However, [FltPlan.com](https://www.fltplan.com/canadianapproachplates.htm) claims to provide free, up-to-date charts:

> In cooperation with Nav Canada, FltPlan.com is pleased to announce
>   free Canadian Approach Plates, also know as CAP (Canada Air Pilot).
>   These online charts include all instrument approaches, airport
>   diagrams, SIDs, STARs, and special use approach plates for Canadian
>   Airports. They work similarly to the already available U.S. approach
>   plates.
>
> CAP is an extension of FltPlan.com's continuously expanding coverage
>   of Canada, Mexico, Latin America and the Caribbean. In May of this
>   year, we expanded our coverage to include the filing of IFR
>   intra-Canada flight plans. The availability of free, online Canadian
>   Approach Plates brings a new level of safety and convenience for
>   pilots in the planning stages of their trip.

Though I have not seen anything from Nav Canada stating that this is "in cooperation with Nav Canada", they do [seem to be an authorised distributor](http://www.navcanada.ca/EN/products-and-services/Pages/List-Distributors.aspx) of paper charts.

Note [FltPlan.com](https://www.fltplan.com/canadianapproachplates.htm) warns that these charts shall not be printed as a replacement for "proper" paper charts -- I am not sure whether these are deemed to be official or not, but it is rather unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no official source of free Canadian Aeronautical Publications which can be printed for use.