# Are the airport "taxi" plans available online?

Tags: airport, taxiing, eu

Whenever I sit in an aircraft and we taxi around the airport, I wonder how exactly is the airport organized, for example, the arrangement of the taxiways and runways.

Is it possible to locate airport diagrams? I'm mostly interested in Paris CDG, Prague PRG and Amsterdam AMS.

Comment: See this question: [Is there an online source for European Instrument Approach Procedures?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1276/is-there-an-online-source-for-european-instrument-approach-procedures) which would include taxi diagrams like you are asking about.

Comment: Perhaps an interesting destination in that general area is also Austria, charts are available at [VACC Austria](http://www.vacc-austria.org/?page=content/chart_overview).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A great site to download airport diagrams and other charts is [charts.aero](https://charts.aero). As of April 2015, however, the site seems gone.

Airport diagrams show all the taxiways and ramps, which is what you are looking for.

Keep in mind that this is an unofficial website. The charts should not be used for actual navigation.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see any charts for EHAM at the link you've provided... I'm accessing from the USA.

Comment: @JeffBridgman Same here. It may be a temporary issue on the site. I'll keep an eye on it and if it doesn't fix itself I will mention that in the answer.

Comment: @JeffBridgman: Apparently there was some legal problem with European data. It seems to be resolved now, but the URLs changed. Now it is http://charts.aero/?icao=EHAM, or just use the search.

Comment: @PhilippeLeybaert It's still down as of April 2015

Answer (score 12):

In the US, you can find this on the FAA's website [here](http://www.faa.gov/airports/runway_safety/diagrams/). You can search for a US Airport, and it will pull up a Airport diagram with Taxiways, Runup areas, and Runways on it.

I couldn't find an official guide for European airports, but [this site](http://www.bostonvirtualatc.com/charts/index.html) has a detailed [guide for CDG](http://www.bostonvirtualatc.com/charts/index.html?Page=LFPG_index.html), among others, with a [taxiway map](http://www.bostonvirtualatc.com/charts/LFPG/AD/AD%202%20LFPG%20OACI%201%20%28Aerodrome%20Chart%29.pdf) being one component. They also have a similar guide for [AMS](http://www.bostonvirtualatc.com/charts/index.html?Page=EHAM_index.html). They do not have one for PRG. Keep in mind these are unofficial charts.

[image: CDG Airport Diagram]

As Lnafziger noted, [this site](http://www.ead.eurocontrol.int/eadcms/eadsite/index.php.html) also has airport charts, including approaches. The downside is you must register (free) first to access them. You can read more in [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/1277/774).

Comment: The only place I could find PRG charts was at the site Phillipe linked to. They are [here](https://charts.aero/airport/PRG). The site Lnafziger *may* have them, but I haven't registered to find out yet

Comment: Yes, official airport charts for Europe are available from Eurocontrol's [EAD](http://www.ead.eurocontrol.int) You'll need an account (free) and Java (which utterly and truly sucks, even though it says it's plain html, it's lying to you, not to mention the applet is really slow)

Comment: Yeah I linked to that at the bottom of my answer. Apparently you *can* change it to html, but you have to log in through the Java version first.

Answer (score 6):

If you look up the ICAO code, e.g. here

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Civil_Aviation_Organization_airport_code

then Google for the code + charts, e.g "EGLL charts", you will usually find what you're looking for.

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=egll+charts

Answer (score 5):

Airport ground charts are always part of the [AIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeronautical_Information_Publication) (Airport Information Publication). They are usually publicly available in electronic format, but not always easy to find. Wikipedia's entry for AIP has a

For european airports, you can get them from [Eurocontrol](http://www.ead.eurocontrol.int/eadcms/eadsite/index.php.html) (requires registration).

However, you can also usually get these directly from the country's CAA or AIS. Here's the ones you asked for (be aware these links may only work for a short period of time):

[Paris CDG](https://www.sia.aviation-civile.gouv.fr/aip/enligne/FRANCE/NON%20AIRAC-2015-04-02/html/eAIP/Cartes/MIA/LFPG/AD%202%20LFPG%20OACI%2001.pdf).

[Amsterdam Schiphol](http://www.ais-netherlands.nl/aim/2015-02-19-AIRAC/eAIP/html/graphics/eAIP/EH-AD-2.EHAM-ADC-A2s.pdf).

[Prague](http://lis.rlp.cz/ais_data/aip/data/valid/a2-pr-adc.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Just stumbled across this directory, hosted by VATSIM. Doesn't appear to be entirely up to date but does provide a link for charts for Prague, among many others. (Includes links to content that may be behind a paywall though).

http://www.vatsim.net/charts/